# Experience points for solved low level sidequests?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have solved some forgotten low level quests
(I'm actually at level 20, the side quests at level 12 and 14).

This quests where worth only 5 XP points.

Do you know how big the difference between the actual character level and the quest level should be to gain the maximum possible points?
Is 5 XP points the minimum we get for a solved low level side quest more then 5 level under the actual character level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a quest is more than 5 levels below you (turning the quest level color from green to grey in your journal), then you get a tiny xp reward.  If you want the maximum xp reward, the quest should be completed while its still "green" for you.  The actual numbers depend on the quest itself.  5 xp is not the minimum for all "grey" quests, its just the amount that quest pays out when it is "grey".  Some "grey" quests may pay out a little more than that, and some may pay out none at all.